# Axios call in recursive function - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, recursion, axios, jsonschema

I'm new to vue.js. In my code, I try to recurse JSON schema and get all the nested properties in a single object. In some cases, fetch properties from API calls. kindly guide.

JSON Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "UNDP",
  "description": "UNDP PRISM Data Capturing Form",
  "type": "object",
  "x-display": "form",
  "properties": {
    "concepts": {
      "title": "Concepts",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "indicators": {
          "$ref": "/Form/GetIndicators"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My function

```
parseJsonToObject(schema:any) {
    if (!schema) { return }

    if(schema.$ref) {
        let params = {
            id: schema.id
        };
        let response = $axios.get(schema.$ref, params);     
        schema.properties = response.data.properties;
    }

    if (schema.type === 'string' || schema.type === 'number') {
        return schema.title;
    }

    const parsedData = {};
    
    Object.keys(schema.properties || {}).forEach( (item) => {
        parsedData[item] = this.parseDomainSchemaToObject(schema.properties[item])
    })

    return parsedData
}
```

I got the result

```
{
  "concepts": {
      "indicators": {}
  }
}
```

I have also tried async/await

```
async parseToObject(schema:any) {   
    let response = await this.getRefPropertiesFormServer(schema.$ref, params) ;
    // code
}

async getRefPropertiesFormServer(url, params){
    return $axios.get(url, params);
}
```

then I got below result

```
{
      "concepts": {
          "indicators": new Promise()
      }
}
```

Comment: "I have also tried async/await" - what exactly?

Comment: That snippet doesn't contain problems. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . I don't see how you could get `"indicators": new Promise()` with async/await if you used it correctly.

Comment: I got the result where **parseToObject** function is called.

`let parsedObject = parseToObject(schema)`
this line returned result with `"indicators": new Promise()` first then only inside axios call triggering.

Comment: You need to propagate async/await to the entire call stack, should be let parsedObject = await parseToObject(schema)